# when fb logged out button is pressed shall I log out the user out of my site as well?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am using the Facebook Javascript and PHP sdk.

I have a FB login button that when clicked the user is prompted for all the necessary permissions etc and the gets access to my website (a new record is created for this).

The question is what is the best practice for logout normally used and why ?

1)Show the facebook logout button and upon click disconnect the user from fb disconnect and from my website as well.

2)Do not show the FB logout button at all and just display the normal log out button to disconnect the user from my website only.

Comment: [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) _require_ you to offer the user a possibility to log out of your site _and_ Facebook at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should log the user out of facebook when the log out button is pressed, as this would log them out of facebook, therefore as i understand it, they need to login to facebook in order to use your website, so it's treated as an account on your website by them verifying themselves via their own facebook account?

So if they are logging into your website via logging into their facebook account, it's probably best to log them out of both your website and facebook when the log out button is clicked IMO.

This means it may be easier for them to accomplish logging out of your site when they have finished, however there is the problem that they may ONLY want to log out of your website and NOT facebook... which is what im assuming you are asking about. In this case, i don't know if it would be possible, but you could create an account for them when they successfully login to your website using their FB account, using their details, etc and have a seperate log out button just to log them out of your website...

I hope i have helped in some way and if not... sorry and GL :-)

Comment: "ONLY want to log out of your website and NOT facebook... which is what im assuming you are asking about" yes that's what I am asking so maybe I need to have two log out buttons but this will be confusing ... I guess I can just have the button to let them log out from my website and hide the Facebook log out button when they log in (they can go to facebook if the like to log out from there) .

Comment: I agree... i think if they want to log out of facebook, then can do that on facebook. Doing so may then mean they can't access your website, however if you provide the ability for them to login, then this should be sufficient. This being said, i think it would be a good idea to only show the log out of the website button so its not too confusing...